# In FastAPI routers folder have multiple python files how to share Database connection

Tags: fastapi

My FastAPI project has multiple python file in routers folder and db.py connection (are not using ORM) the modules folder. In db.py has database class with connection/simple SELECT operations. We import database class in the reach routers file to interact with DB. I'm new to python to programming please advise how can I make DB connection without importing DB class in reach file? how do I make one DB connection share it across other router files? kindly advise best approach to my use case and also provide some sample code

here is db.py

```
def __init__(self):
  self.dbconn = psycopg2.connect(host=HOST, database=DBNAME, user=USER)
  self.rco = psycopg2.connect(host=HOST, database=DBNAME, user=USER)
  self.rc = self.rco.cursor()
  self.wco = psycopg2.connect(host=HOST, database=DBNAME, user=USER)
  self.wc = self.wco.cursor()
  self.rco.autocommit = True
  self.rconn.set_session(readonly=True)
  self.wconn.autocommit = True
```